# React component does not infer children in StencilJS

Tags: reactjs, web-component, stenciljs

I am using StencilJS to create some web components. I created a utility component since I saw myself reusing some logic again and again:

```
export type ConditionalRenderProps = {
  condition: boolean;
};

const ConditionalRender = ({ condition, children }: React.PropsWithChildren<ConditionalRenderProps>) => {
  return condition && children ? children : null;
};
```

However, when I use it as such in a Stencil component, the children props is undefined:

```
Component({
  tag: 'foo',
  styleUrl: 'foo.css'
  shadow: true,
})
export class Foo {

  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        <ConditionalRender condition={true}>
          <span>foo</span>
        </ConditionalRender>
      </Host>
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a catch? Why is `children` undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing React and Stencil, which won't work like that.

You can instead use a Stencil functional component, the main difference being that the children are passed in a second argument:

```
import { FunctionalComponent } from '@stencil/core';

export type ConditionalRenderProps = {
  condition: boolean;
};

export const ConditionalRender: FunctionalComponent<ConditionalRenderProps> = ({ condition }, children) => {
  return condition && children ? children : [];
};
```

**Update**

Previously, the code would return `null` if the condition wasn't `true`. Since the return type of Functional Components is `VNode | VNode[]` I changed it to an empty array instead.