# Return null from StencilJS FunctionalComponent

Tags: typescript, jsx, stenciljs

I have a StencilJS FunctionalComponent.  The component evaluates some condition and based on this either returns jsx or null.  I want to return null because on such occasions I don't want the component to render or even exist.

However, I get a compiler error in Typescript:
`Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'VNode | VNode[]'.ts(2322)`

How do I then return an empty VNode that instructs the upper layer to render nothing without returning null?

Answer (score 0):

Since Functional Components only render their children, without a wrapping element, returning no children is the right approach.

Since the return value is `VNode | VNode[]` you can return an empty array. That way the Functional Component will render nothing.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77840452/1242317) for an example.